# Can't access Meteor.user() property

Tags: meteor, typescript

I've installed a Meteor phone authentication package `mys:accounts-phone`, which should add a  `phone.number` subfield into users collection. I try to access this field as follows:

```
Meteor.user().phone.number
```

but typescript shows error

> Property 'phone' does not exist on type 'User'.

On the other hand, I have custom props in users.profile, and can easily access them in this way.
Insecure is not yet removed. Autopublish is ON.

Comment: is there a way to print or otherwise view all the keys under the object `Meteor.user()`?

Comment: { 
 "_id" : "xk67327YLKYeiPnKE", 
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-19T12:21:55.692Z"), 
 "services" : { 
  "phone" : {  }, 
  "resume" : { 
   "loginTokens" : [ 
    { 
     "when" : ISODate("2017-01-19T12:22:05.008Z"),
     "hashedToken" :"CLBi1T8fthuGOqpiS2alZw7kaGmoiAYiCC4nJZoTssc=" 
    } ] 
  } 
 }, 
 "phone" : { 
  "number" : "+9721234567", 
  "verified" : true }, 
 "profile" : { 
  "name" : "Lф11", 
  "regNum" : "Х205НА77" } }

Comment: This is extract from DB. Actually I do not know how to get Meteor.user() object keys. Another strange thing, by Ctrl-Space Idea shows username property, which is absent in DB.

Comment: Could you try access `Meteor.user().phone.number` in browser console?

Comment: Yes. It's accessible through console and provide correct value.

Answer (score 0):

this happens sometime when our angular component is initialized but our meteor data is not reached from server. 
try to use user injection in place of Meteor.user()

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import { InjectUser } from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';//<--**** import this****

 @Component({
        selector: "login-buttons",
        template
    })
 @InjectUser('user') //<--*** add this***
 export class LoginButtonsComponent {
        user: Meteor.User; //<--*** add this ***
        constructor(private router: Router) {}
 }
```

now in user variable you will have all values of Meteor.User

if you want to print in html part use this

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  {{user.phone.number}}
</div>
```

don't forget to install

```
meteor add accounts-password

meteor npm install --save angular2-meteor-accounts-ui
```

and in app.module.ts file

```
  import { AccountsModule } from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ... other modules here
    AccountsModule
  ],
```

hope this will work. if this not work let me know i will tell you one other solution

Comment: I am using accounts-phone package so there is no need for accounts-password, right? Also, there is no any description or documentation about angular2-meteor-accounts-ui. I am using Ionic 2 fo frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Got probable answer from Meteor [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-user).

It explains why username property appears. By default, Meteor publish only a number of fields considered to be public. To exposure any additional fields they must be published explicitly.

Not yet have time to test, but think it should work.

The other reason, with the same sympthoms, when publication code do not executed at server side. Try to put

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
    Meteor.publish('userData', function() {
        if(!this.userId) return null;
        return Meteor.users.find(this.userId
            //, {fields: {lastname: 1,}}
        );
    });
});
```

in a file within `/server` folder of your application.